# How to make sure randomly generated fiber don't intersect with the trim circle?

Tags: python, matrix, random, abaqus, fibers

[random generated fiber in polymer matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqh7Z.png)

I create a randomly fiber generated in python and execute in abaqus. I want to make sure the random fiber generated didnt intersect with the trim circle on the left as shown in the image uploaded. Please help.

i have tried modified code, I added an additional check for intersection with the trim circle. After generating each new fiber, it is checked for intersection with both existing fibers and the trim circle. If an intersection is detected, the variable intersection_exists is set to True. This ensures that fibers that intersect with the trim circle are not included in the CentList and are not counted towards the fiber volume fraction.But it still intersect.

**Here is the code:**

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from caeModules import *
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup
from random import *
from math import *

executeOnCaeStartup()

# Function to check the intersection of a circle with a list of circles
def intersection(R1, Cen1, R2, Cen2, Tol):
    Distan = ((Cen1[0] - Cen2[0]) ** 2.0 + (Cen1[1] - Cen2[1]) ** 2.0) ** 0.5
    Min_Dis = R1 + R2 + Tol

    if Distan > Min_Dis:
        Intersection = 'No'
    else:
        Intersection = 'Yes'

    return Intersection

def ran(X1, X2):
    value = (X2 - X1) * random() + X1
    return value

Wcomp = 2.0  # Adjust the matrix width
Hcomp = 6.0  # Adjust the matrix height
Rmin = 0.1
Rmax = 0.1
Tol = 0.001

Vf_target = 0.3  # Target fiber volume fraction (30%)
Vff = 0.0

CentList = []

while Vff < Vf_target:
    CentList = []`

    Vff = 0.0

    while Vff < Vf_target:
        Newcircle = [ran(Rmax, Wcomp - Rmax), ran(Rmax, Hcomp - Rmax), ran(Rmin, Rmax)]

        # Check for intersection with existing fibers
        intersection_exists = False
        for Cent in CentList:
            R = Cent[2]
            Check = intersection(R, Cent, Newcircle[2], Newcircle, Tol)
            if Check == 'Yes':
                intersection_exists = True
                break

        # Check for intersection with matrix boundaries
        if (Newcircle[0] - Newcircle[2] < 0 + Tol or
                Newcircle[0] + Newcircle[2] > Wcomp - Tol or
                Newcircle[1] - Newcircle[2] < 0 + Tol or
                Newcircle[1] + Newcircle[2] > Hcomp - Tol):
            intersection_exists = True

        if not intersection_exists:
            CentList.append(Newcircle)
            Vff += pi * Newcircle[2] ** 2.0 / (Wcomp * Hcomp)

        # Check for intersection with trim circle
        trim_circle_center = (0.0, Hcomp / 2)
        trim_circle_radius = 3.375
        trim_check = intersection(Newcircle[2], Newcircle, trim_circle_radius, trim_circle_center, Tol)
        if trim_check == 'Yes':
            intersection_exists = True

        if not intersection_exists:
            CentList.append(Newcircle)
            Vff += pi * Newcircle[2] ** 2.0 / (Wcomp * Hcomp)


    print(Vff)

print(CentList)

# Create Part (Matrix)
s = mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=20.0)
g, v, d, c = s.geometry, s.vertices, s.dimensions, s.constraints
s.setPrimaryObject(option=STANDALONE)
s.rectangle(point1=(0.0, 0.0), point2=(Wcomp, Hcomp))
s.CircleByCenterPerimeter(center=(0.0, Hcomp/2), point1=(0.0, 3.375))
s.CoincidentConstraint(entity1=v[4], entity2=g[2], addUndoState=False)
s.EqualDistanceConstraint(entity1=v[0], entity2=v[1], midpoint=v[4], 
    addUndoState=False)
s.autoTrimCurve(curve1=g[6], point1=(-0.232322692871094, 2.57432436943054))
s.autoTrimCurve(curve1=g[2], point1=(-0.0296030044555664, 3.15962839126587))
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].Part(name='Plate', dimensionality=TWO_D_PLANAR, 
    type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Plate']
p.BaseShell(sketch=s)
s.unsetPrimaryObject()
session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=p)
del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']

# Partition
f, e, d1 = p.faces, p.edges, p.datums
t = p.MakeSketchTransform(sketchPlane=f[0], sketchPlaneSide=SIDE1, origin=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
s = mdb.models['Model-1'].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=1.0, gridSpacing=0.01, transform=t)
g, v, d, c = s.geometry, s.vertices, s.dimensions, s.constraints
s.setPrimaryObject(option=SUPERIMPOSE)
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Plate']

# Generate random fibers
for Cent in CentList:
    X = Cent[0]
    Y = Cent[1]
    R = Cent[2]
    p.projectReferencesOntoSketch(sketch=s, filter=COPLANAR_EDGES)
    s.CircleByCenterPerimeter(center=(X, Y), point1=(X + R, Y))

p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Plate']
f = p.faces
pickedFaces = f.getSequenceFromMask(mask=('[#1 ]',), )
pickedFaces = f[:]
e1, d2 = p.edges, p.datums
p.PartitionFaceBySketch(faces=pickedFaces, sketch=s)
s.unsetPrimaryObject()
del mdb.models['Model-1'].sketches['__profile__']



#Property

#Matrix
mdb.models['Model-1'].Material(name='Matrix')
mdb.models['Model-1'].materials['Matrix'].Elastic(table=((3000.0, 0.3), ))
mdb.models['Model-1'].HomogeneousSolidSection(name='Section-2', 
    material='Matrix', thickness=None)
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Plate']
f = p.faces
faces = f.findAt((0,0,0))
q=faces.index
Fac = f[q:q+1]
region = p.Set(faces=Fac, name='Set-Matrix')
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['Plate']
p.SectionAssignment(region=region, sectionName='Section-2', offset=0.0, 
    offsetType=MIDDLE_SURFACE, offsetField='', 
    thicknessAssignment=FROM_SECTION)

#fibers
mdb.models['Model-1'].Material(name='Fiber')
mdb.models['Model-1'].materials['Fiber'].Elastic(table=((70000.0, 0.3), ))
mdb.models['Model-1'].HomogeneousSolidSection(name='Section-1', 
    material='Fiber', thickness=None)
f = p.faces

i = 1
for Cent in CentList:
    X = Cent[0]
    Y = Cent[1]
    R = Cent[2]
    
# Find faces and assign section to each fiber
for i, Cent in enumerate(CentList):
    X = Cent[0]
    Y = Cent[1]
    R = Cent[2]
    
    faces = f.findAt((X, Y, 0))
    if faces:
        q = faces.index
        Fac = f[q:q+1]
        region = p.Set(faces=Fac, name='Set-1'+str(i+1))
        p.SectionAssignment(region=region, sectionName='Section-1', offset=0.0,
                            offsetType=MIDDLE_SURFACE, offsetField='',
                            thicknessAssignment=FROM_SECTION)
    else:
        print("No faces found at coordinates ({X}, {Y})".format(X=X, Y=Y))
```

Comment: You really need to make a [mcve] - not only is this code not currently runnable, long, and technical - but as someone who has studied FRC, the thing you're trying to do has had whole doctorate studies done on it.  I suggest looking up the prior art on "fiber-fiber interactions" and ask questions about specific implementation details in what you find.

Comment: Hint: the method you're using is not guaranteed to converge on a solution in finite time, and at `Vff=0.3` is almost guaranteed not to.  See [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264127522003720)